# Relation does not exist postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a simple consult:

```
select * from database.table
```

but it return that the relation does not exist, how can be possible? I put the database and the table exists.

I tried things like test with the `information_schema` and i have the same issue.

Comment: you connect to a `database` and then query `schema.table`

Comment: To follow up on the comment from @JGH, are you coming from MySQL? There database = schema. In Postgres they are not the same and you cannot do a cross database query without using something like [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) or [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html).

Comment: That's not your real query since both `database` and `table` are reserved words. What is the real query and could you also share the DDL for this table? And a database is not the same thing as a schema, you connect to a database and you can use the objects in a certain namespace, the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you troubleshoot the issue in the following ways:

1.Check that you are connected to the correct database. You can do this by running the following query:

```
SELECT current_database();
```

2.Verify that you are logged in as a user with the correct permissions to access the table. You can check this by running the following command:

```
SELECT has_table_privilege('databasename.tablename', 'SELECT');
```

3.Check that the table exists in the database you are connected to. You can do this by running the following query:

```
\dt
```

4.Check that the table name is spelled correctly.

5.Check that the table is in the same schema as the one you are currently using. You can change the current schema by running the following query:

```
SELECT schemaname 
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE tablename = 'table_name' 
 AND schemaname = 'schema_name';
```

6.Make sure that you are not using a reserved word as a table name.
such as database and table